# Inno Setup doesn't run program post install

Tags: python, inno-setup, pyinstaller

I'm encountering a weird bug concerning Inno Setup. I have a Python program packaged with PyInstaller that detects and downloads updates to itself (which are also Inno installers).

When the user runs the setup file by itself, running the program post install works. But, when I run the setup EXE from within the program, the whole setup still runs, but the post install doesn't work.

I made sure that my process was completely separate and disjoint with the following code:

```
CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008

kwargs = {}
kwargs.update(creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
kwargs.update(close_fds=True)

p = subprocess.Popen('"' + exePath + '"', **kwargs)
```

What's really frustrating with this is that running this from the original Python program works! It's only when it is packaged with PyInstaller that the post install doesn't work.

I have no idea where to look to figure out this problem nor how to debug it. Your ideas and theories are much appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is a small test program that demonstrates my problems (file called test_runner.py):

```
import subprocess

def run_exe(exePath):
    '''
    Runs a .exe on Windows in a 100% separate environment.
    '''
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200
    DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008

    kwargs = {}
    kwargs.update(creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
    kwargs.update(close_fds=True)

    p = subprocess.Popen('"' + exePath + '"', **kwargs)

path = r'<some absolute path>\setup.exe'

run_exe(path)
```

I then compiled it with:

```
pyinstaller.py test_runner.py
```

Comment: just use the latest pyinstaller ... it has an option that closes the existing running program before installing ...

Comment: Where? I don't see it anywhere in the arguments of `pyinstaller.py` nor in the .spec. Also, the program closes itself right after the above code is run.

Comment: And what does your Inno postinstall look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out that I had to clear the environment variables `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` so that the PyInstaller-packaged program can generate the correct paths for those variables (they were set by the previous PyInstaller-packaged program that spawned the setup).

I ended up making the Inno Setup run a batch file that cleared them before running the executable. I hope this helps someone out there.